# jQuery fancybox: Safari, first click blank screen, subsequent clicks ok. TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: jquery, magento, safari, fancybox

I am having a strange issue where fancybox loads a blank screen on the first click, but works every time subsequently.

An example page this occurs can be found here: https://shop.pb0110.de/en/women/ab1-totebag-bag-blue-leather.html

The error I see in the console is:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'v.deletedIds.pop()')`

Oddly enough it doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: You should post relevant code which gives the error, people don't like to search and bring back the ball...

Comment: this https://shop.pb0110.de/skin/frontend/pb0110/default/js/jquery.hashchange.min.js is using some deprecated elements not compatible with the jQuery version you are using therefore there are js errors that void your other plugins to work properly. I would downgrade to jQuery v1.8.3 to be safe.